# Can you use Azure DevOps Test Plans to discover TDD Unit Tests?

Tags: unit-tests, qa-role, tdd, azure-devops

On Azure DevOps, Test Plans, are Test Plans ever used in determining TDD Unit Tests?  Quality Assurance may add their own tests later, but initially, during development, is there any reason why the Devs and QA cannot use the Test Plans in Azure DevOps to discover your TDD Unit Tests?

I did not see anything here, but I did look:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422034/is-there-a-way-to-use-azure-devops-test-plan-parameters-for-each-test-case-as-pa/59670731#59670731

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620845/should-you-associate-unit-tests-with-test-plans-in-azure-devops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DevOps Test Plans is a service that provides a suite of testing tools for continuous testing in your development pipeline. It enables you to plan, track, and manage your testing efforts, including manual and exploratory testing, automated testing, and continuous testing.

Test Plans can be used to discover and run TDD (Test-Driven Development) unit tests. TDD is a software development practice that involves writing tests before writing the code. By doing this, the developer is able to confirm that their code is working as expected before it is written.

In Azure DevOps, developers can use the Test Explorer to run unit tests and see the results. The Test Explorer displays a list of all the tests in a solution, organized by project, and allows developers to run tests, debug tests, and analyze test results.

You can associate your TDD unit tests with Test Plans in Azure DevOps. To do this, you need to set up a build pipeline that compiles and runs your unit tests. You can then configure your Test Plan to include the results of these unit tests in its reporting.

Here are some reference sources that you can use to learn more about Azure DevOps Test Plans and TDD:

1. Azure DevOps Test Plans official documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/test-plans/index?view=azure-devops
2. Test-Driven Development (TDD) with Visual Studio and .NET Core by Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test
3. Test-Driven Development (TDD) Fundamentals by Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/test-driven-development-tdd/
4. Test-Driven Development (TDD) by Martin Fowler: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDrivenDevelopment.html
5. Test-Driven Development (TDD) - The Complete Guide by Udemy: https://www.udemy.com/course/test-driven-development-tdd/

I hope this helps.